# Get count of list items that meet a condition with Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a list of dictionaries where each dict has a boolean entry. I want to display the items that are `True`, along with the count of those items. I'm using the `selectattr` filter, but it returns a generator, and calling `|length` on it raise an error.  How can I get the length of the items returned from `selectattr` in Jinja?

```
my_list = [{foo=False, ...}, {foo=True, ...}, ...]
```

```
{{ my_list|selectattr('foo', 'equalto', True)|length }}
```

Comment: It's better to keep logic out of templates. But if you still will do it, @larsks 's approach is pretty good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a `list` filter that will transform a generator into a list.  So:

```
{{ my_list|selectattr('foo')|list|length }}
```

Comment: How would I do this if the keys weren't using boolean values, say 1,2,3. And I want to get the length of all items where foo == 3

Comment: You probably want to post that as a new question (because it's really not possible to reply with code or config examples in a comment)

Comment: Figured it out `{ my_list|selectattr('foo', 'equalto', 'xyz')|list|length }}`