# 'Any' and 'all' filters for jinja2 (Ansible)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have trouble to find basic filters for a list: 'any' (return `true` if any value in the list can be casted to `true`), 'all' (return `true` only of all values in the list can be casted to `true`).

I can emulate `any` by using `my_list|map()|bool`, but it looks like a hack, and I have trouble with `all` function.

UPD:

I found this (yet another strange) hack.

- any: `my_list|map('bool')|max`
- all: `my_list|map('bool')|min`

Are there better (idiomatic) ways?

Comment: found below with similar use case please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006617/get-count-of-list-items-that-meet-a-condition-with-jinja2

Comment: I saw it. They want to filter the list, not to implement any/all functions.

Answer (score 2):

*2022 answer and ansible.core version 2.12 (I don't know the answers on past versions):*

use the `is any` and `is all` syntax instead of the non-working `| any` / `| all` or any other hack you proposed

example copied from https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html

```yaml
vars:
  mylist:
      - 1
      - "{{ 3 == 3 }}"
      - True
  myotherlist:
      - False
      - True
tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "all are true!"
    when: mylist is all

  - debug:
      msg: "at least one is true"
    when: myotherlist is any
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you don't need `any` or `all` when it comes to a list of booleans. I'm happily using `max` and `min` instead, relying on the fact that `True > False` :)

```
any([False, False, False]): {{ [False, False, False] | max }} 
any([False, True, False]): {{ [False, True, False] | max }} 
all([True, True, False]): {{ [True, True, False ] | min }} 
all([True, True, True]): {{ [True, True, True] | min }}
```

renders to

```
any([False, False, False]): False 
any([False, True, False]): True 
all([True, True, False]): False 
all([True, True, True]): True
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can just use `all` and `any`.

Here is an example playbook using them. (This works for me with Ansible 2.5.1.)

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - assert:
       that:
         - mixed | any
         - not (mixed | all)
         - all_true | any
         - all_true | all
         - not (all_false | any)
         - not (all_false | all)
     vars:
       mixed:
         - false
         - true
         - false
       all_true:
         - true
         - true
         - true
       all_false:
         - false
         - false
         - false
```

Comment: `template error while templating string: no filter named 'all'.`

Comment: Which version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: Probably something from the future, as any or all do not exist.

Answer (score -1):

Ansible does not implement `any` and `all` filters.